# How to add bower component to gulp app

Tags: coffeescript, gulp, bower, strongloop, textangular

I am not sure the title is correct but i am new with Bower, Gulp, Strongloop and even AngularJS.

I am updating an existing app, using bower, gulp and Strongloop, and i would like to add a bower componenent to the app (this one : https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular).

i did `bower install textAngular` as explained in the readme file, but now i should add those lines to my app :

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/bower_components/textAngular/dist/textAngular.css'>
<script src='/bower_components/textAngular/dist/textAngular-rangy.min.js'></script>
<script src='/bower_components/textAngular/dist/textAngular-sanitize.min.js'></script>
<script src='/bower_components/textAngular/dist/textAngular.min.js'></script>
```

But my app is using Strongloop, gulp and coffee script, so there is lot of file, not looking like classic html file and i am totally lost.

Can you help me find the next step to make this works ?
Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found my mistake, i need to add --saved at the end of bower command line.

So real line is : `bower install textAngular --saved`

Plus i should add textAngular in my angular module definition :

```
angular.module "starter", [
...
"textAngular"
...
]
```

Note that you should install too font-awesome and rangy to make it works completly